# What is the best software for creating exam paper template?

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation, page-layout, tools, print-production

I regularly create exam papers in Photoshop with two types of pages: left and right.

We create the questions in Word and then add them into Photoshop. However, this process takes a lot of time and the resulting PDF is quite large and non-vector.

What is the best software we can use to create vector PDF outputs but still be able to use our design?

Comment: could you add any example of the pages you create?

Comment: @llan I've added an example of one of our left pages :)

Comment: I would use some typesetting program such as [Scribus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribus).

Comment: If you write the questions in Word, why do you need to get them into any other program? Can't you just make the layout in Word and then export to PDF directly?

Comment: Why are you using Photoshop at all??? As Janus points out.. why can't you just use Word?

Comment: @Metis the problem could be the lack of support or knowhow with laying out the formulas and the rows they have below. OP could use Cambria and Cambria Math for equations and creating 1cm high tables with inside horizontal ruled rows. If push comes to shove OP could hire a typesetter to do the job if learning to do it themselves is too labour intensive. Also depending on OP's ability TeX or LaTeX could be the ultimate solution.

Comment: This will likely come in handy as well... https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11271/indesign-how-to-create-lines-for-form-design

Comment: for basic formulae, I would recommend onenote. it has similar text options to word but also some LaTex support within the also otherwise very useful equation editor. It takes some getting used to the shortcuts to become fast, but I use it for all my note-taking as a student in my math classes

Comment: Are you aware of https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Also, I believe Pierson has software for making tests, and other publishers likely the same. That said, I found their software ended up limiting me when I wanted to create certain types of questions rather than helping. I've used Tex, InDesign, and textbook software, but ended up finding I was just adding learning time when each platform had their own peculiarities, rather than using the little tricks I'd picked up in Word (you can do an amazing things, it's just not all intuitive; skill builds on any tool you keep using). The only thing I used GIMP for was creating occasional raster graphics

Comment: Why is this not closed as opinion based yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Photoshop is probably the last choice for this type of work.

InDesign could work better as it can natively create a 'facing pages' document, meaning left & right page templates and yes with the proper formatting everything can be vector in your template which will result in minimal file size.

Since you appear to also need to typeset math into your documents that means installing a third party plugin, of which several are available, just google 'indesign math plugin' and see which one works for you.

Scribus or LaTeX are other free alternatives as others have explained already in more detail.

Comment: Great. If you feel this answers your question try clicking the _check_ icon and the _up_ arrow next to my answer above. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but InDesign is far from _ideal_.

Comment: I agree with that, so just edited my answer.

Answer (score 42):

[LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) is meant exactly for stuff like this. LaTeX is a programming language of sorts, designed with the explicit purpose of typesetting documents... like, say, an essay template. It spits out nice, vectorized PDFs across Windows, OSX, and Linux, and it's also possible to define your own custom formats and commands.

[There's a wealth of documentation available online](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), which enables even complete beginners to get up and running pretty quickly. Services like [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) allow collaboration and versioning, as well as including features that users of word processors take for granted (e.g. a spell checker).

And, just as a fun example, the output from a bit of LaTeX "code". The snippet `$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{z^*}{x^2 + y^2}$` yields this:

[image]

Which you might recognize as the equation in the example exam page. Oh, and when rendered as a PDF, even the math stuff comes out as copy-able text (though, depending on where you're copying to, results may vary).

There's also a [TeX/LaTeX StackExchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for your more advanced questions. Like, say, [how to typeset an exam paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286/121293). (Thanks @Gallifreyan!)

Comment: Don't forget the variety of packages for typesetting exams specifically.

Comment: There is this handy quesion: [How can I typeset an exam or assignment paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286/126615)

Comment: LaTex yes yes yes, thousand times yes for this. It might seem daunting at first but it gets easier and easier.

Comment: And dont forget that once you get the design, you can use macros and all the work to be done is to write down the questions. All the other - apge layout, barcodes (QRcodes) will be generated automatically using macros...

Comment: '$' for maths mode is deprecated. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode

Comment: The thing is it may not be worth the time for a teacher to learn if they're only spending a short time each year making tests, most of which is quite easy and straightforward with Word, especially with a few quick tweaks such as adding Greek letter toolbars. I had a quick taste of LaTex while working on my thesis, but when I was teaching and time was short, I found it easier to stick with Word, which I was more familiar with for word processing (and generally offered more layout options/tools, easier drawings, etc). I find every time I use Tex (or MathJax here!) I have to recheck cheatsheets

Comment: @JeopardyTempest: While that may be, the OP did not make mention of his level of skill with any particular software package besides PhotoShop. And, in my experience and semi-professional opinion, LaTeX is a better tool for this kind of thing than Word because it's possible to create repeatable, smart templates and macros in a way that it's hard to do in Word.

Comment: @TheoreticalPerson No, it's not deprecated. `$$...$$` is deprecated in Latex, but `$...$` is perfectly acceptable and used by most. Nowhere does the page you link to say otherwise.

Comment: LaTeX also got a big community of professionals who can dhare how to create good graphs, circuits or whatever special imagery your field needs.

Comment: To see what LaTeX (or TeX) can do, refer to [Showcase of beautiful typography done in TeX & friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/126615), and if OP is not in STEM, see [What would draw a student of the humanities to (La)TeX systems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132649/126615)

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz Maybe worth including some nice possibilities with latex: automatically calculating number of total points, randomly choosing questions from a pool of questions, generating questions and answer documents at the same time ....

Answer (score 3):

As some people mentioned before, it would be great and highly recommended to use Adobe InDesign to create something like that. The result will be much lighter than Adobe Photoshop (for the PDF file size). But, you can do it more easy by using your Microsoft Word to export as PDF. You can do it by click File - Save As - and then choose PDF format.

In case if you don't see the option, you need to install any PDF software. From my own experience, I love to use [Foxit PhantomPDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/) rather than Adobe Acrobat. But, it's up to you.

Comment: Word 2010 and newer have have [built-in PDF export](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-or-convert-to-PDF-D85416C5-7D77-4FD6-A216-6F4BF7C7C110), so it had to be a really old version of Word to need external PDF software.

Comment: I agree with you. I said that just in case someone using an old version of Microsoft Word. I am using Microsoft Word 2016 right now.

Comment: In fact, Word 2007 had the PDF export capability available as an add-in from the get-go and it became a built-in feature in one of the service packs.

Answer (score 3):

I would do that in Word itself.

1. [Left and right pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=Left%20and%20right%20Pages%20Word) (Checked)
2. [Template for the background](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-background-or-color-of-a-document-6ce0b23e-b833-4421-b8c3-b3d637e62524) (your design) (Checked)
3. [Math formulas](https://www.google.com/search?q=Math%20formulas%20Word) (Checked)

In case you need a really complex one that you can not write inside Word you could write somewhere else and copy paste inside Word.

4. Print as PDF. You simply print a file to Mircosoft to PDF virtual printer. If you do not have it, you can use a free one like PDF creator on Windows.

And you can simply prepare some preformatted styles for some types of equations, so you assign font and size with one click.

Comment: Or save it as PDF - not all computers have a virtual PDF printer.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Some recent versions of Word have, in my experience, developed a bad habit of horrifically mangling PDF output. It's visually readable, but copy/pasting, for instance, yields garbage because the PDF wasn't created properly.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz That's just because your PDF viewer doesn't read non-standard Word metadata. Definitely the fault of the viewer. :-D

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I'd call that an indictment of Word more than anything. Standards exist for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

[I created](http://www.dlugosz.com/nb/notepaper/npdesign1.html) lined paper using a script (Perl in my case) to write SVG+css.  This is then merged with other elements to put on the page (personal logo, special text, etc.) in Inkscape (free software) and then output to a very small PDF.

My notes on making nice lines, more details, and the script is on the linked page.

You can, more generally, hand-craft a single SVG object for one stave and produce a more optimal (small!) PDF file. But creating it in Inkscape is easy and good enough for most people.  Then use that object (cloned for each answer blank) and text typed in Inkscape for your page.

Answer (score 0):

Use InDesign and use illustrator if you wish to draw complicated illustrations in the paper. InDesign will give you complete control over the output pdf. You can control everything about the output pdf. and you can also have left and right pages side by side.